# how do i limit characters in view with Symfony 4? (character_limiter CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, symfony

I want to show only 20 characters from description of an item. For example, in PHP/CodeIgniter we can use `<td><?= character_limiter($item['description'], 20); ?></td>` which 20 is the amount of characters that i want to show. How to do this in Symfony 4?

Code:

```
<thead>
 <tr>
   <td>Description</td>
 </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
{% for item in itens %}
 <tr>
   <td> {{item.description}} </td>
 </tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using TWIG you can use:

```
{{ item.description | slice(0, 20) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str_limit` function in twig

```
{{ str_limit(item.description, 20) }}
```